# How to load external webpage in webview? I need to load the advertise when clicked button of webview

Tags: android, webview

I need to open the external webpage from webview when clicked in the button of webpage! I solved the problem of how to open the external link by using `WebChromeClient` and overriding `onJsConfirm()` function. Now I need to show the external link in same webview with smaller size and I have option to cancel the external webpage(custom advertised page) in same `WebView` activity! Help needed.

```
final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle("App Titler")
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                result.confirm();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                result.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                .create()
                .show();

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you edit the webpage you are loading in the `WebView`?

Comment: sorry! I didn't get what 'edit' you are saying! I can use all functionality of the webpage! but the external page opens by taking all the space of mobile! and when i click back the webpage doesn't open!!

Comment: Do you mean the external link opens in your phones browser? And you want to open links inside your app itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(pass your url here);
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: I have used it! It only execute the main webpage! I need to make it work for another webpage that will load when certain button is clicked in webview